# iOS core data extract NSString out of fetch

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsstring

I have set up a table view controller listing all the unique exercises. So my fetch and everything works. I also put it into a table with the following lines

```
    NSManagedObject *exercise = [self.exercises objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [exercise valueForKey:@"exercise"]]];
```

However when I try to send the selected element to another view controller I get a weird object. It functionally runs  as a string and prints a string on the next view controller. however when I do some further querying in the core data, the object is not really a string so it fetches empty.

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showGraph"]) {
    ProgressGraphViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
           destViewController.exercise = [_exercises objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}
```

}
@end

This is what the data looks like when i breakpoint and inspect 
[image]

What is NSKnownKeysDictionary1 and how can i get a string out of it?

Comment: Check the response type of your fetch request, it should be set to be NSManagedObject.

Comment: Have you specified `.resultType = .DictionaryResultType` when you execute the fetch?  The `NSKnownKeysDictionary` is what is returned in that case.

Answer (score 0):

As @Andy mentioned ,check object type. if its ManagedObject type better pass it in managedObject property else do casting of that object. 
Better change Property "exercise" from NSString to NSManagedObject.